# Automatically plots in shiny

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am using R programming and I want to make automatically plots   on numerical and categorical variables, with summary

I am using shiny library

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a histogram for a numerical variable in shiny using ggplot2:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data, aes(x = variable))+
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)})
```

Comment: Thanks for Ur response but how will be automatically separate numerical and categorical variable and then how will draw automatically plots on the variables based

Comment: You can use the mutate function in the dplyr library to create a new variable with the value "numeric" or "factor" depending on the data type of the original variable.
for (col in names(data)) {
  if (is.numeric(data[[col]])) {
    output[[paste0("plot_", col)]] <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data, aes(x = col)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
    })
  } else if (is.factor(data[[col]])) {
    output[[paste0("plot_", col)]] <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data, aes(x = col)) +
        geom_bar()
    })
  }
}